Visual Studio 2022 generate empty moc files with define
My QtExample.h with Q_OBJECT has an #ifdef _FEATURE. The #ifdef wraps the class. In Project -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions, this _FEATURE is specified. When moc.exe runs during the Visual Studio build, my moc_QtExample.cpp is generated empty, as if moc.exe doesn't see the define. But when I run moc.exe in the command line and manually specify moc.exe -D _FEATURE QtExample.h -o moc_QtExample.cpp, the moc_QtExample.cpp file is generated correctly. I understand that Visual Studio with CMake will probably work. But I need it specifically within Qt/MsBuild.
I tried:

In Project -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions, this _FEATURE is specified.
In the *.vcxproj file, specify _FEATURE</...></...> for the configuration.


I'm sorry, my Visual Studio version is 2022. It was a copy-paste of the title from a similar issue, but there was nothing about define

I guess there is a custom build step to run moc, either added by you or generated by qmake. Could you not just edit that custom build step to add the -D_FEATURE option?

In Visual Studio there are three ways to use Qt: 1) it being external tool and ran by custom build steps in vcxproj, 2) Qt usage by ninja/CMake or 3) some "new approach" from 2018 that I have never heard any good words about.

Solved. Custom Build worked great for my case. Standard QtMoc doesn't work well with #ifdef in *.h of qt classes.
In more detail, right-click on the file with #ifdef and Q_OBJECT and select Properties. Replace QtMoc with Custom Build. In Properties->Custom Build Tool->General->Command Line, enter a line with moc.exe -D FEATURE . Don't forget to include moc*.cpp in the project. Usually, QtMoc does both moc and CIComplite.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
